# Akka HTTP client - Unmarshal with Play JSON

Tags: scala, unmarshalling, akka-http, play-json

I am using Akka HTTP as a client to do a POST request and parse the answer. I am using Play JSON and I get the following compiler error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller[akka.http.javadsl.model.ResponseEntity,B]
[ERROR]       Unmarshal(response.entity).to[B].recoverWith {
```

This is the dependency I added to use Play JSON instead of Spray:

```
"de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-play-json"
```

My class definition is:

```
class HttpClient(implicit val system: ActorSystem, val materializer: Materializer) extends PlayJsonSupport {
```

and the method definition is:

```
private def parseResponse[B](response: HttpResponse)(implicit reads: Reads[B]): Future[B] = {
  if (response.status().isSuccess) {
    Unmarshal(response.entity).to[B].recoverWith {
    ....
```

In the imports I have:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpplayjson.PlayJsonSupport._
```

It seems to me that I have the required implicits in scope. The `Marshal` part has a similar logic (but with `Writes` instead of `Reads`) and compiles fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your other imports. Based on the error message, it appears that you're using `akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse` instead of `akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse`; [`PlayJsonSupport`](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/blob/v1.20.1/akka-http-play-json/src/main/scala/de/heikoseeberger/akkahttpplayjson/PlayJsonSupport.scala) only supports the Scala DSL:

```
private def parseResponse[B](response: HttpResponse)(implicit reads: Reads[B]): Future[B] = ???
                                    // ^ this should be akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
```

In other words, use

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
```

instead of

```
import akka.http.javadsl.model._
```

Comment: Oh.. wow. Silly mistake. I added the imports automatically with IntelliJ and didn't even notice that. Another pair of eyes always helps, thanks a lot!